# how is stored procedure helpful in JPA?

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures

I am creating a web application using JSF (front-end) and EclipseLink JPA to persist data into MySQL DB for manipulation of data (add, update, delete). I am in a dilemma, if I should use stored procedure along with JPA or JPA alone would suffice.

Do I really need to use SP or JPA alone would suffice?

If yes, how is SP goin to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i really need to use SP or JPA alone would suffice?

JPA alone will suffice.

If you need very specific database operations (such as proprietary functions of your database), JPA won't be optimal (as it tries to be database independent), but will still alow you to use such proprietary functions.

> how is SP goin to help me?

Today, the use of SP is highly debatable. It can be considered a bad practice. I won't enter into details as it is very well documented here: [Who Needs Stored Procedures, Anyways?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html)

Bottom line is:

**Stored Procedures should be considered database assembly language: for use in only the most performance critical situations.**

In other words: make your app using JPA and adding business logic to classes and objects only. If, god forbid, some part of your system has such a complicated query or sequence of database operations that JPA is taking a very long time to execute, then use a stored procedure.